# Normalisation of a wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, normalization

> If the system if found in the state: $$\psi=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi}}(\frac1{\sqrt3}e^{-i3\phi}+ce^{-i4\phi})$$ what value of $c$ normalizes the wavefunction?

Clearly: $$\int_0^{2\pi}\psi^*\psi d\psi=1$$

But I get to the following point and can get no further:

$$\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac13+c^*c+\frac1{\sqrt3}c^*e^{i \phi} + \frac1{\sqrt3}ce^{-i \phi}=1$$

I'm not sure if it's necessary to put $c^*$ and $c$, please could you clear up whether this is necessary. Also, please tell me where I go from here in order to find c.

Comment: It looks to me as if c is real as everything else in $\psi$ is real - also, of course, your should have $1/2\pi$ in front....

Comment: integration of $e^{i\theta}$ from 0 to $2\pi$ is 0, thus you would get a solution were the magnitude of c will be a fixed real number, that is if you have by mistake missed i in your exponential

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By normalization condition you get$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac13+c^*c+\frac1{\sqrt3}c^*e^{i \phi} + \frac1{\sqrt3}ce^{-i \phi}=2\pi$$ Now we know that $e^{i\theta}=\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta}$ thus its integration over a period of $2\pi$ is 0. Thus our equation reduces to
$$cc^*=\frac{2}{3}$$
Thus any complex number who's magnitude or modulus is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ makes your wave function normalized.